# Struct returning different things from reader and hash accessor

Tags: ruby

I have a struct like this:

```
class Item < Struct.new(:url, :list)
  def list
    @list ||= Array.new
  end
end
```

I found out today that the `.list()` and `[:list]` returns different things:

```
i = Item.new
#=> #<struct Item url=nil, list=nil>
i.list
#=> []
i[:list]
#=> nil
i.list << 1
#=> [1]
i.list += [2]
#=> [1, 2]
i.list
#=> [1]
i[:list]
#=> [1, 2]
```

Why is this and how can I write my struct to have default empty array properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the other advantages of Struct and need to stick with it, you could write your own `initialize` method:

```
class Item < Struct.new(:url, :list)
  def initialize(url, list = nil)
    self.url  = url
    self.list = Array(list)
  end
end
```

`Array()` will ensure anything passed in will be put in an array if it's not one already, and will return an empty array (`[]`) if `nil` is the argument.

Comment: Oops! So sorry, I edited *your* answer instead of mine! Stupid me. (Do keep the `.equals` thing though :-) ) - let me clean it up for you!

Answer (score 2):

Someone already answered the 'why' bit, so maybe if you still want to do this with `Struct`, then why not try this:

```
class Item < Struct.new(:url, :list)
  def list
    self[:list] ||= Array.new
  end
end
```

This works because while `@list` is an instance variable of your making, the accessor that `Struct` provides it it's own. (`:list`). `self[:list]` lets you get at it.

```
i = Item.new # =>  #<struct Item url=nil, list=nil>
i.list   # => []
i[:list] # => []
# Compare using OBJECT IDENTITY (is i.list internally the same thing as i[:list]?)
i[:list].equal? i.list # true
i.list << 1   # => [1]
i.list += [2] # => [1, 2]
i.list        # => [1, 2]
i[:list]      # => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should better use [Dash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie) instead of Struct. Look:

```
require 'hashie'

class Item < Hashie::Dash
  property :url
  property :list, default: []
end

i = Item.new # => #<Item list=[]>
i.list # => []
i[:list] # => []
i.list << 1 # => [1]
i.list += [2] # => [1, 2]
i.list # => [1, 2]
i[:list] # => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sergio Tulentsev [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13697663/struct-returning-different-things-from-reader-and-hash-accessor/13697885#13697885) the `how can I write my struct to have default empty array properly?` part, so I'll write the `Why is this?` part.
I am missing information but with a structure, it is written [*::new creates a new class, named by aString, containing accessor methods for the given symbols.*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Struct.html#method-c-new)

So you have a accessor for `:list` but it is still different from your `@list` attribute. This means, you can name `@list` as you want, it will not be affiliated to the `:list` of the struct.
You also override the symbol accessor the struct was previously providing with your `def list; end`

```
i.list << 1   # adding 1 to @list set to Array.new
#=> [1]
i.list += [2] # equals i.list = i.list + [2]
              # i.list= is the `:list` setter method.
              # i.list is the @list getter method.
              # It equals :list = @list + [2]
#=> [1, 2]
i.list        # @list
#=> [1]
i[:list]      # :list
#=> [1, 2]
```